# Dog command to drop in Italian

Tags: word-choice

I'm training my dog by giving commands in Italian and wondering is there any specific word to tell a dog to drop something from a mouth. I believe both "cadere" or "scendere" could be used but I'm wondering is there a common "doggy" word for it.

Thank you.

And sorry for quite vague tag as I have no reputation to create specific one.

Comment: Neither *cadere* (= “to fall”) nor *scendere* (= “to go down”) mean “drop”; if anything, something like *lascia* o *molla*, but I don't know a thing about dogs.

Comment: Don't use the infinitive, use the imperative. "Lascia" makes the most sense to me.

Comment: The word language doesn't matter, for the dog is only a sound. It must associate the word to a behaviour, like "vieni" to "come to you" http://www.ag-educatorecinofilo.it".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best word is "lascia" from verb "lasciare", as you can see from lots of websites (for instance, http://it.m.wikihow.com/Insegnare-il-%22Lascia%22-al-tuo-Cane, https://www.cani.it/magazine/comando-lascia/n271.html, http://www.zampefelici.it/insegnare-al-cane-lasciare/).

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Exactly! How could I forget! Lasciatemi cantare. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Remember your dog does not speak Italian or English for that matter; the meaning of the word you use is more important to you than your dog.  Just be consistent with the word and visual cue you use for the action you want the dog to take.  I would consider give me, (Mi dia) with the emphasis on “dia” and point with my off hand, left if right handed, to the ground in front of my feet.

Comment: Wholeo, *mi dia*, really? I'd say you might be on first-name terms with your dog and dare tell them *dammi*.